# Marker clusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker, markerclusterer

I would like to ask whether is my code's error or wrong arrangement of code.
    The sidebar is shown and the infowindow also. But the marker still can't be clustered.(why?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html  >
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body >



    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>
        </td>
        <td width = 150 valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;">
           <div id="side_bar"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar
      var side_bar_html = "";

      // arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar
      // because the function closure trick doesnt work there
      var gmarkers = [];


      // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
      function createMarker(point,name,html) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        });
        // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        // add a line to the side_bar html
        side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';


    return marker;
      }


      // This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
      function myclick(i) {
        GEvent.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
      }


      // create the map
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
      map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng( 43.907787,-79.359741), 8);

      // add the points    
      var point = new GLatLng(43.65654,-79.90138);
      var marker = createMarker(point,"This place","Some stuff to display in the<br>First Info Window")
      map.addOverlay(marker);

      var point = new GLatLng(43.91892,-78.89231);
      var marker = createMarker(point,"That place","Some stuff to display in the<br>Second Info Window")
      map.addOverlay(marker);

      var point = new GLatLng(43.82589,-78.89231);
      var marker = createMarker(point,"The other place","Some stuff to display in the<br>Third Info Window")
      map.addOverlay(marker);


          var markers = [];

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        imagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/images/m2.png',
        gridSize: 10,
        minimumClusterSize: 2
    });


    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);                          




      // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
      document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;



    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope someone can take a look at this,your help will be appreciated .Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a few problems there.

**1st problem:**

You should not be using `gMap2` because it has been deprecated since 2013. Google have since rewritten its maps javascript library, making it more lightweight and compatible for mobile devices and it is version 3.

V3 example:

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    {
        zoom: 6,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
```

**2nd problem:**

Array `markers` is empty. You are creating the `MarkerClusterer` object correctly but it has been fed with an empty array. It should be an array of markers that you want the clusterer object to consider for clustering.

```
 var markers = [];
 ...
 var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

**3rd problem:**

You are re-instantiating the variable `marker` over and over again. Try to give them distinct names like `marker1`, `marker2`... This is so that you can reference back the markers later in code.

```
 var marker = createMarker(point,"This place","Some stuff to display in the<br>First Info Window")
 var marker = createMarker(point,"That place","Some stuff to display in the<br>Second Info Window")
 ...
```

**4th problem**

This is the **MOST** important one. You should not **EXPOSE** your Google map API keys to the public!!! This gives me an opportunity to do malicious things to it and I believe you may have breach the license agreement. Please don't do it again. I'll modify your post to censor that part off.

Here is a clusterer example that I have made in JSFiddle previously.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/bvu6vgxu/1/)